# mongorestore of specific database from full dump - safe?

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I must restore a single Mongodb database from a full backup of many databases
without touching the other databases:

e.g. $ mongorestore --gzip --drop --db ONEDB dbbackupfile

Will the restore command honour the --db ONEDB and ONLY drop the ONEDB database collection? Or will it drop them all?

[The documentation for mongorestore only says that --drop will drop all collections in the backup - it doesn't say what effect the --db option has on the --drop flag...]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the fear of dropping all your databases,

With that being said the documentation clearly states:

> drops the collections from the target database.

i recommend that if your experimenting with this command for the first time and you're not confident with it yet you should test it not on production but on your local first, or at the very least run it with --dryRun flag just to see if your getting the results you want.